# m2eclipse cannot update index from central repo

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, configuration, m2eclipse

I have just downloaded and installed M2Eclipse, but it fails to update the index of the central repo.
At the same time, Maven itself is able to download artifacts from the repo (via command line).

I had the `settings.xml` file in `maven/conf`, and I copied it to `.m2/` directory, but it didn't help.

I have proxy, but proxy settings are given in `settings.xml` - commands from command line work fine, but not in Eclipse. In Eclipse it gives me this:

```
Unable to update index for central|http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
```

**UPDATE:**

This is what I get when I try to create a new Maven Project:

```
Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:RELEASE from any of the configured repositories.
Could not resolve artifact
Failed to resolve version for org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:RELEASE: Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Documents and Settings\user\.m2\repository)
Failed to resolve version for org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:RELEASE: Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Documents and Settings\user\.m2\repository)
```

Comment: Is your proxy using NTLM Authentication? Because I have exact the same problem.

Answer (score 7):

Please check your m2eclipse installations configuration, have you pointed it to the correct settings.xml file ?

[image]

Comment: Yes, my Installation Properties look pretty much the same as yours

I've checked the settings.xml files - they're the same both in .m2\ and in maven\conf

Answer (score 7):

Just add this mirror to the `settings.xml`:

```
<mirror>
  <id>ibiblio.org</id>
  <url>http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven2</url>
  <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
</mirror>
```

Comment: Thanks! That was my problem. Maybe I'm a little bit old, but can you explain why eclipse does not include it from the beginning this mirror?

Comment: Because it only works with the central repository in general.

Comment: i comment just to not forget that it's the solution for the index problem in Spring STS 3.6.3 :)

Answer (score 4):

if you are behind a proxy do your proxy settings on your usersettings file as below

```
<proxies>
    <proxy>
        <id>myId</id>
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <username>MyUser</username>
        <password>MyPassword</password>
        <host>my.proxy.host</host>
        <port>myproxyport</port>
        <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
</proxies>
```

Comment: This managed to solve my problem, thanks! OP should consider accepting an answer.

Comment: Additionally: If you don't have a settings.xml file under {USER_HOME}\.m2 folder. Simply create one and put your proxy settings into it. And import that file to your Maven installation settings.

Answer (score 2):

Changes in both global and user specific settings/xml are needed in order custom maven installation to work inside eclipse. I don't know why but it helped for me.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is not about connection/proxy, try a more drastic way: delete the whole .metadata folder. Later import projects from their place or checkout them from the svn(if you use some). This is not much more complicated, but it helped. the problem is that we don't really know, what metadata are broken, so the natural next step is to delete all of them. I think, it is the deepest possible cleaning before reinstallation of Eclipse + plugins.

Answer (score -2):

To avoid having to change the settings in 2 places and just rely on the global settings this works nicely:

```
ln -s /etc/maven2/settings.xml ~/.m2/settings.xml
```

Comment: This answer is an overall software configuration optimization and does not address the question at all.