# Stopping Maven index update eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, indexing, repository

This question might have been asked before.

Every time I open my eclipse it takes forever to update the Maven repo indexes.

I do not have any Maven Plugin installed on it but still does it.

Does anyone know how to disable this feature because this is becoming pain for me.

thanks

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/13362961/715269

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> Download repository index updates on startup (uncheck)
```

maybe also useful for you

```
Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> Do not automatically update dependencies from remote repositories (check)
```

Answer (score 5):

To Disable index update eclipse  .  It shows  [image] always.

> Step 1

Go Window Tab->Preferences -> Maven

> Step 2

Unchecked

- Download repository index updates on startup
- Do not automatically update dependencies from remote repositories

[image]

[image]

> Step 3

Click Ok- >Restart Eclipse

Comment: Does 'Unchecking' : Do not automatically update dependencies from remote repositories option would enable the auto update?

Answer (score 2):

If you have something like this (note the `<updatePolicy>`):

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>foo-bar-repository</id>
        <url>http://foo.bar.com/repository</url>
        <snapshots>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

This can screw up your Eclipse and force it to try downloading the jars each time.
You can set this to:

```
            <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
```

or some other interval as described [here.](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.4/maven-settings/settings.html)

Comment: This is about updating the libraries but not the repository index - as asked in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, after disabling the update as suggested by FrVaBe, if keeps updating, try to update the user settings. It worked for me

```
Preferences->Maven->User Settings->Update Settings
```

Comment: So, I should downvote FrVabe's answer just because it need 1 more step for me to  work? you are crazy Makky.

Comment: I am not crazy but I think you are. May be you are not understanding it properly. What exactly you are answering here?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project preferences and then go to Builders. Disable the Maven builder. This should stop the index updates. I guess you will need to do this on each project in your workspace, I don't think you can do this for the whole workspace.

Comment: I do not have Maven Builder into any of the project.I think this could be Eclipse setup....

Comment: -1 Why was this answer upvoted - it does not provide any useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Eclipse Mars in Windows 10.Until application run as Administrator mode maven could not fetch the updates to .m2 folder.