# Why eclipse keep updating index, even past 100%

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno, maven-eclipse-plugin

My eclipse juno always keep updating maven index, even when it is past 100%. Is there anything wrong with this?

Comment: [Disable it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514814/stopping-maven-index-update-eclipse)

Comment: You mean the plugin? its maven plugin and I can't really disable it as most of my project use that

Comment: No no, disable the auto-indexing.