# Google GSON Dependency not found

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, gson

I am trying to have GSON in my pom.xml but IntelliJ is telling me that the dependency "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0" not found. I have tried calling the Maven repository but it still is not working. Also ignore the commented out lines.

Here is a copy of my pom file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>TagChooser</groupId>
<artifactId>TagChooser 1.7.10</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


<dependencies>

    <!--  Gson: Java to Json conversion -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>mkremins</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>fanciful</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>0.4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->

</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Maven repository</name>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>

    <!--<repository>-->
        <!--<id>stealthyone-repo</id>-->
        <!--<url>http://repo.stealthyone.com/content/groups/public</url>-->
    <!--</repository>-->

</repositories>
```

Comment: Try the mirror http://stackoverflow.com/a/11942110/573032

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I remembered how to do this real quick. You have to go to File -> Project Structure. Then click the Libraries tab and the the green plus. Once clicked select from Maven and then search GSON and find the correct GSON version you want to use from the menu and then GSON dependency will work.

Comment: There is no such option like Libraries in Project Structure

Comment: Yes there is. 
File -> Project Structure -> Left panel says Project Settings at the top, and you'll see it under there.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue.

Go to File -> Invalidate Caches/ Restart and click the same again.

Android Studio restarts and reloads all your library files.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and Invalidate caches and restart (in android studio) didn't work for me. Sometimes the IDE doesn't recognize the class that is being tried to be imported.

Add dependency in build.gradle(:app) in gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'
}
```

And add the line:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson
```

Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
   <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
   <version>2.8.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: An explanation with this would help improve this answer